# How Keyword and Numeric data Types are stored in elastic search? is it stored in inverted index?

Tags: elasticsearch

```
put sana/_mapping/learn { "properties": { "name":{"type":"text"}, "age":{"type":"integer"} } }

POST sana/learn { "name":"rosy", "age":23 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting the Elasticsearch doc:

> Most fields are indexed by default, which makes them searchable. The
>   inverted index allows queries to look up the search term in unique
>   sorted list of terms, and from that immediately have access to the
>   list of documents that contain the term.

Keyword and numeric data types are also indexed and stored in the inverted index so that these fields are searchable, but if you want you can disable it by setting [index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-index.html) type to false, in your index mapping, also on these fields(keyword,numeric) [doc_values](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/doc-values.html) is enabled by default sorting and aggregations etc, but not enabled on analyzed string(text) fields.

Hope I answered your question and let me know if you have any doubt.